# Update multiple columns with function returning multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update a table with the multiple returns of a function.

I have created a TYPE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE city_state AS OBJECT
(
  city VARCHAR2(30),
  state VARCHAR2(2)
);
/
```

and I have a function that returns a variable of this type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION closestcity(lat IN NUMBER, lon IN NUMBER) RETURN city_state IS
...
```

I need to update a table that contains city, state, latitude and longitude columns. With the lat/lon, I should call the function and use the result to update the value of the city/state. I only want to call the function once for each row and there are only some rows that I need to update (let's say city is NULL)

This is what I got so far

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM t t1 WHERE city IS NULL)
SET (city, state) = (
                     SELECT newcity.city, newcity.state FROM
                       ( SELECT closestcity(latitude, longitude) newcity
                         FROM t t2
                         WHERE t1.latitude = t2.latitude AND
                               t1.longitude = t2.longitude)
                    );
```

but I get an invalid identifir error. I feel like I'm overcomplicating it, what would be the correct approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you've got that error is because Oracle attempts to qualify `newcity` referenced in the `SELECT newcity.city, newcity.state` select statement. It cannot find the object `newcity` and thus throws the error. Also alias the inline view as `t1` if you really need it. As @Rene [has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13578634/997660), you can successfully replace it with the table name.  To that end you may rewrite your update statement as follows:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM t t1 WHERE city IS NULL) t1
   SET (city, state) = (
                         SELECT closestcity(latitude, longitude).city 
                              , closestcity(latitude, longitude).state
                           FROM t t2
                          WHERE t1.latitude = t2.latitude 
                            AND t1.longitude = t2.longitude 
                        );
```

Or simply:

```
UPDATE t t1 
   SET city  = closestcity(latitude, longitude).city 
     , state = closestcity(latitude, longitude).state
where t1.city is null
```

**Update#1**

```
update (select nd.newdata.city  as newcity
             , nd.newdata.state as newstate
             , city
             , state
          from (                             
                 SELECT closestcity(latitude, longitude) newdata
                      , city
                      , state
                   FROM t
                  where city is null
                ) nd
              ) q  
set q.city  = q.newcity
  , q.state = q.newstate
```

Comment: This works, but I end up calling closestcity twice - and it's a very heavy function

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be:

```
UPDATE <table1>
set (<column1>, <column2>) = (select <column1>,<column2> 
                              from <table2> 
                              where <where clause table2 > )
where <where clause table1>
```

So your query should be:

```
UPDATE t1
SET (city, state) = (SELECT closestcity(latitude, longitude) newcity
                            ,state
                       FROM t t2
                      WHERE t1.latitude = t2.latitude 
                        AND t1.longitude = t2.longitude)
where city IS NULL
```

Comment: state is a variable of newcity (just like city is), I can't select it directly

Answer (score 0):

Just one change

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM t WHERE city IS NULL) **t1**
SET (city, state) = (
                     SELECT newcity.city, newcity.state FROM
                       ( SELECT closestcity(latitude, longitude) newcity
                         FROM t t2
                         WHERE t1.latitude = t2.latitude AND
                               t1.longitude = t2.longitude)
                    );
```

Comment: I get `ORA-00904: "T1"."LONGITUDE": invalid identifier
`